# display Foreign Key values in Django haystack search results

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am new to django and haystack. Can anyone please help me with this code. 
I have the below Models in models.py file

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    zip_code = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=True)

class UserProfessional(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, unique=True, related_name = 'user_professionals')
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    professional_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=PROFESSIONAL_TYPE)
    bio_exp = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

**The search criteria would be zip_code, city and state. So we can search by zip code but the results should display the company, and bio_exp.**

Comment: You might want to more clearly state what the problem is and what "not working" means. If you want to be able to filter search results on e.g. zip code or state, you'd want to add those fields to your index.

Comment: This can be done without needing a bunch of prepare_FIELD methods using the mode_attr field attribute: zip_code = indexes.CharField(model_attr="userprofile__zip_code")

Comment: @ChrisAdams I have included this following in search template, so my search is working fine {{ object.zip_code }}
{{ object.street_address }}
{{ object.city }}

Comment: @ChrisAdams But I can't see bio_exp in my search results, that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have created a SearchIndex which will index UserProfessional and not UserProfile.

```
class UserProfessionalIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    userprofile = indexes.CharField(model_attr='userprofile')

    def get_model(self):
        return UserProfessional
```

and in the search template specify

```
{{ object.userprofile.zip_code }}
{{ object. bio_exp }}
```

Now search for zip_code and other params and you will get back bio_exp from UserProfessional and other fields.

Hope this helps.

Comment: in this django templates to access the value, will it work?      <h4>{{ result.object.bio_exp }} </h4>
                                      <h4>{{ result.object.company }}</h4>

Comment: Yes when reading the search result it will work. My explanation above was for template while indexing the data.

Comment: Oh ok got it, Can you please help me with the diff between the Index Class and index template? What each will do here..

Comment: Template helps you to control the fields that you want to index. e.g There may be a case where you do not want to index everything in UserProfessional. By explicitly specifying in template you can control that. Take a look at [this example](https://waaave.com/tutorial/django/django-design-a-complete-search-engine-with-haystack-and-whoosh/).